# JsonMappingException + Unable to deserialize

Tags: json, deserialization, json-deserialization

This is my first post to the community. Am trying to de-serialize a payload to a class and consistently failing in the attempt. I went through other similar posts related to the exception from the site but nothing fixed my problem. All that am trying to do is map the payload to the class MessageBody.class and get extract the payload corresponding to the element 'Message' via the getMessage getter. Can you please help with this?

Thanks

MessageBody class

```html
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MessageBody {

    @SerializedName("Message")
    @JsonProperty("Message")
    private String mMessage;

    public MessageBody() {
    }

    public MessageBody(String message) {
        this.mMessage = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.mMessage = message;
    }
}
```

De-serialization attempt code

```html
private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String payload = "{\"Message\" : {\"simpleId\":{\"id\":\"44\"},\"dV\":{\"v\":1},\"pId\":{\"pId\":\"977\"},\"state\":\"start\"}}";
    MessageBody messageBody = objectMapper.readValue(
                payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), MessageBody.class);
}
```

Exception thrown

```html
 [java] Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
     [java]  at [Source: [B@45812b51; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: MessageBody["Message"])
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:44)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:13)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:579)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
     [java]  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1935)
```